# Set div to the end of the container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I replace my div to the end of the holder div? I have this here:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content1">My text 1</div>
    <div id="content2">My text 2</div>
    <div id="content3">My text 3</div>
</div>
```

And I want to put my content1 to the end with JavaScript (or JQuery):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content2">My text 2</div>
    <div id="content3">My text 3</div>
    <div id="content1">My text 1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` will always move the element to the last position in the parent element

```
$('#container').append($('#content1'));
```

or even just move the first element to the last position

```
$('#container').append(function() {
    return $(this).children().first();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it in jQuery:

```js
$('#content1').insertAfter('#content3');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content1">My text 1</div>
    <div id="content2">My text 2</div>
    <div id="content3">My text 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I don't know the exactly what is the content of the container div

Comment: In that case, @adeneo's response is better.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var container = $("#container");
$(":eq(0)", container).appendTo(container);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content1">My text 1</div>
    <div id="content2">My text 2</div>
    <div id="content3">My text 3</div>
</div>
```